# ¿Cómo añadir el resultado de los métodos al html creado?

Tags: javascript, html5

```
function Gato(nombre, fechaNac, raza, peso) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.fechaNac = fechaNac;
    this.raza = raza;
    this.peso = peso;
    this.estado = "jugando";
}


Gato.prototype.alimentarGato = function() {
    this.estado = "comiendo";
    return this.peso += 1;
}
Gato.prototype.jugar = function () {

    this.estado = "jugando";
    this.peso -= 1;
}

Gato.prototype.dormir = function () {
    this.estado = "durmiendo";
}

function abrirVentana (){
    var miVentana=window.open("","","width=400,height=400,scrollbars=NO,top=0, left=0");
    var contenido= '<html><head><title>ventana'+gato1.nombre+'</title>'
        +'<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gato.js"></script>'
        +'</head>'
        +'<body><div id="contenedor">'
        +'<input type="button" value="Cerrar" onclick="opener.cerrarNuevaVentana(window)" />'

        //MOSTRAR PESO GATO
        +'<div id="pesoCat"></div>'
        +'<input type="button" value="Alimentar" onclick="opener.gato1.alimentarGato()" />'
        +'<input type="button" value="jugar"  />'
        +'<input type="button" value="dormir"  />'
        +'</div>'
        +'</body></html>';
    miVentana.document.open();
    miVentana.document.write(contenido);
    miVentana.document.close();

    miVentana.document.getElementById("pesoCat").innerHTML = gato1.alimentarGato();
}

function cerrarNuevaVentana(ventana){
    ventana.close();
}

var gato1 = new Gato("Lumy", "2005", "Persa", 5);


abrirVentana();
```

Comment: Fíjate que tienes dos símbolos `>` al cerrar la etiqueta `<head>`

Comment: el elemento con id pesoCat , no está en tu actual documento, sino en la nueva ventana creada

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes que hacer es actualizar el peso del gato *cada* vez que lo modifiques (es decir, cuando pulses uno de los tres botones que lo hacen). En tu código, sólo lo calculas la primera vez y te olvidas.

Sería algo así:

```js
function Gato(nombre, fechaNac, raza, peso) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.fechaNac = fechaNac;
    this.raza = raza;
    this.peso = peso;
    this.estado = "jugando";
}


Gato.prototype.alimentarGato = function() {
    this.estado = "comiendo";
    return this.peso += 1;
}
Gato.prototype.jugar = function () {

    this.estado = "jugando";
    this.peso -= 1;
}

Gato.prototype.dormir = function () {
    this.estado = "durmiendo";
}

function abrirVentana (){
    var miVentana=window.open("","","width=400,height=400,scrollbars=NO,top=0, left=0");
    var contenido= '<html><head><title>ventana'+gato1.nombre+'</title>'
        +'<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gato.js"></script>'
        +'</head>'
        +'<body><div id="contenedor">'
        +'<input type="button" value="Cerrar" onclick="opener.cerrarNuevaVentana(window)" />'

        //MOSTRAR PESO GATO
        +'<div id="pesoCat"></div>'
        +'<input type="button" value="Alimentar" onclick="opener.gato1.alimentarGato(); opener.actualizarPesoGato(window, opener.gato1)" />'
        +'<input type="button" value="jugar" onclick="opener.gato1.jugar(); opener.actualizarPesoGato(window, opener.gato1)" />'
        +'<input type="button" value="dormir" onclick="opener.gato1.dormir(); opener.actualizarPesoGato(window, opener.gato1)" />'
        +'</div>'
        +'</body></html>';
    miVentana.document.open();
    miVentana.document.write(contenido);
    miVentana.document.close();

    miVentana.document.getElementById("pesoCat").innerHTML = gato1.alimentarGato();
}

function cerrarNuevaVentana(ventana){
    ventana.close();
}

function actualizarPesoGato(ventana, gato) {
    ventana.document.getElementById("pesoCat").innerHTML = gato.peso;
}

var gato1 = new Gato("Lumy", "2005", "Persa", 5);


abrirVentana();
```

Comment: Podrías dar una explicación de por que está en lo correcto tu respuesta?

Comment: @Ajeno solucionado, gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Con respecto a tu pregunta, el problema está en que en la línea:

```
document.getElementById("pesoCat").innerHTML = gato1.alimentarGato();
```

Estás usando el objeto `document` de la ventana principal, pero el elemento
`< div id="pesoCat">< /div>` no está dentro de ese documento, la linea debería decir:

```
miVentana.document.getElementById("pesoCat").innerHTML = gato1.alimentarGato();
```

y por supuesto, eso requerirá que ajustes un poco el resto del código (por ejemplo hacer que `miVentana` sea una variable global, o colocar este nuevo script dentro de la nueva ventana).

Adicionalmente, debes revisar el HTML que estás generando desde `abrirVentana ()`: < la etiqueta `title` le falta un "<".

Comment: Gracias, pero me sigue dando el mismo error, no hay manera :(

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar **jquery** para manejar mejor esos eventos, te va a facilitar mucho el manejo de objetos dentro del DOM.

```
 var peso = gato1.alimentarGato();
 $('#pesoCat').html(peso);
```

o

```
 $('#pesoCat').text(peso);
```

o lo puedes hacer con **javascript**

```
 var pesoGato = document.getElementById("pesoCat");
 pesoGato.textContent = peso;
```

Comment: La práctica debe realizarse exclusivamente con javascript, gracias